# Running VNC from PHP on ubuntu16.04 error: getpassword error: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to start up vnc4server from my php. So far it's running from a start.sh with this in

```
vncserver -geometry 1000x800 -depth 24
export HOME=/home/psych
cd /home/psych/mw3/Infected/
screen -d -m bash -c "export DISPLAY=:1 ; wine iw5mp_server.exe +params...";
```

in my apache2 error.log i have this:

```
You will require a password to access your desktops.

getpassword error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

It looks as though it's asking me to set a password for it from my php but I'm not sure how to do this, or how to disable getpassword.

Note: the php command i'm using

```
shell_exec('HOME=home/psych && sh/home/psych/mw3/Infected/start.sh');
```

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be an encrypted passwd for that user in ~[user]/.vnc/passwd

You normally generate the password interactively with the `vncpasswd` command. If you want to automate everything from a script and copy a pre-encrypted .vnc/passwd file **make sure** the permissions are 600.  If not, eg, 644, you'll get the ioctl error.

Took me a long time to find that.